# Loop String from Console and sum odd numbers

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Number: ")
    val num = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var sum = 0
    for (digit in num) {
        if (digit % 2 != 0) {
            sum += digit
        }
    }
    println("$sum")
}
```

I need this loop to go through every digit in the number and sums all the digits that are odd.
It gives me an error on num "For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method"

Comment: For an answer that includes how to accomplish what you want, you're going to need to explain what you expect looping through an integer to do.

Comment: I have updated @chris

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: for example the user inputs 34652312 and it prints 12, that is the sum of all the even algarisms on that number @s1m0nw1

Comment: Does my answer do what you need?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, an algorism is a technique. I think you're looking for "digit". Anyway, 12 is the sum of the odd digits of that number, but your posted code checks for even.

Comment: yes, I translated it wrong, thanks for correcting me, I have changed it to look for odd now @chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot iterate over an `Int` like `num`:

```
val num = readLine()!!.toInt()
```

You can fix it without a loop and by using standard functions `map`, `filter` and `sum`:

```
val sum = readLine()!!.toCharArray()
    .map { it.toString().toInt() }
    .filter { it % 2 != 0 }
    .sum()
```

The `filter`-condition for even numbers would be `it % 2 == 0`

**EDIT**

For your homework, do this:

```
val num = readLine()!!.toCharArray()
var sum = 0
for (a in num) {
    val intVal = a.toString().toInt()
    if (intVal % 2 != 0) {
        sum += intVal
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that fixes it, but is there a more simple way to do that? This is an homework I have to do for my course and we haven't learned map or filter yet, so it would be odd if I used that. thank you

Comment: Sure, I'll add it

Comment: You don't need `.toCharArray()` because `String.iterator()` is defined. You can also go from the `Char` to the number it represents without an intermediate string (`getNumericValue()`), but that's more of an optimization.